# Is it possible to ensure buttons are the same within a button group?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'd like to ensure two radio buttons within a button group occupy an equal amount of width:

```
<div class="d-flex btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Text</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">More Text</label>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

At the moment, the button with more text is wider.

Thanks

Comment: What about giving a `max-width:10px;` for example to the class of your button?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular setup, I would recommend you create a container `div` around each `input` and `label` pair.  Since you already have `d-flex` on your `btn-group`, you can make use of the the flex properties.

Select the `btn-container` divs in your CSS, and give them a `flex-basis: 100px` (you can change the pixel value to whatever size you need).  They will be the same width.  You can also use percentage values, for example, if you have 4 buttons, you can give each `btn-container` a `flex-basis: 25%` for equal distribution.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-container {
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <div class="btn-container">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked/>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Text</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off"/>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">More Text</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are hiding the radio input and only displaying the labels you can do it like this:

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.01px;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Text</label>
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">More Text</label>
</div>
```

If you are using bootstrap, you don't need to put the extra styles on the btn group that I did.  Just put the flex basis on the label.

Comment: Thanks - so when I tried this the btn-container are the right sizes but the inputs don't seem to fill the containers: https://jsfiddle.net/c8xg16rb/

Comment: I also tried adding w-100 class to inputs but that didn't seem to work either..

Comment: Ok I didn't realize bootstrap was displaying the buttons like that.  Updated my response.

Comment: Remove the `btn-container`  divs from your fiddle and it works